# Global variable in c

Tags: c, variables, global

If we declare a variable in the beginning before main function without giving EXTERN keyword, will it be taken as a static global variable(can be accessed only in that file) or can we able to access it from other files?
For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int k;
main()
{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `k` will technically be available to other files (modules) but unless the other files have an `extern int k` declaration, they won't know about the variable and a compile time error will indicate that `k` is unknown in the other file.

Comment: So deoes it work as a static global variable?

Comment: And the usual way to make it visible is to declare `extern int k;` in a header file to be `#include`d by any any `*.c` file that needs to see it. (Which you normally wouldn't do for something defined in the same source file as `main()`.)

Comment: It's "static" in the sense that it has static storage duration; it exists for the entire execution of the program. It has external linkage, which means it's visible to other translation units (source files) has long as they have an `extern` declaration; defining it with the `static` keyword would disable that. The C standard doesn't use the term "global variable", so it's hard to say whether it's a "static global variable".

Comment: @user1762571, it isn't treated as `static` in the strict sense. It's treated as globally accessible by the compiler and the linker. It could be accessed by other files if they have the `extern`. If it were `static`, then even having an `extern` in the other file would not make it accessible to that other file.

Answer (score 1):

external definition and declaration, default initialization to zero.

```
int k;
```

external declaration only, defined and initialized some where else

```
extern int k;
```

external definition, initialization and declaration

```
int k = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int k;
```

It tells the compiler the variable k is accessable at file scocpe, can not be reached outside.

```
extern int k;
```

It tells the linker the variable k is linked to variable k in the other file.

```
int k;
```

It is the global scope, can not declare twice in two files.